# Going from SystemJS to Webpack with Angular 2 2.4

Tags: angular, webpack

I was using SystemJS, just like Angular uses throughout their documentation. I'm now to the point of wanting to bundle things up for dev and prod deployments, so I started following the Webpack tutorial on Angular's website: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#common-configuration

I've finished the tutorial, but I'm getting the following build errors in numerous files:

> Build:Cannot find name 'Set'.
>
> Build:Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> Build:Cannot find name 'Map'.

There are certain parts of the tutorial I wasn't sure about and figure they may be the source of this issue and/or potentially other ones.

One of my biggest concerns is that I strayed away from the documentation slightly when initially building my app (before using Webpack). In an effort to avoid clutter in my app folder, I added the following code to the systemjs.config.js file so that the transpiled javascript files would be sent to a dist folder:

```
map: {
        app: 'Angular2_Apps/Tasks/dist',
        ...
     }
```

I also added the following code to the "compilerOptions" in my tsconfig.json file:

```
"outDir": "dist",
```

Now that my transpiled javascript files are in that dist folder I created, I would ideally like to keep them there for organization purposes. Do I need to change any of the Webpack files to accommodate for that?

Comment: If you just want not to bundle up your compiled javascript then you just need to stick to `systemJS` or switch to `rollup`, because `Webpack` is used to bundle up your codes and it becomes a little bit heavier. Also if you want to use webpack just there is a starter pack which you could modify according to your need. 
`https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter`

Comment: I'd like to bundle my HTML files and eventually my CSS files as well. Is there a straight forward way to do that with SystemJS? Or would Webpack be a better option for that?

Comment: I am also using the `Webpack` to bundle up my all of the `html`, `css` and `js` and i am happy with it. I will bundle them into smaller chunks later on but for the `development` phase it is okey to me. I was using `systemJS` at the beginning but i was not able to bundle the `vendor` codes to single file so i have switched to `Webpack` but i am not sure that `systemJS` bundles all the html and css files, where you evantually would switch to `webpack` or even better to bundle in small size you could switch to `rollup`.

Comment: @Brett, give [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#deploying-the-app-via-github-pages) a go. It's using webpack under the hood.

Comment: @Timathon How stable is Angular CLI? I noticed the GitHub page says it is very much a work in progress and is now in Beta. Is it reliable enough to use?

Comment: @Brett, I know little about real-world production project. Please go to [angular-cli's gitter channel](https://gitter.im/angular/angular-cli?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack will not help you get rid of the most heavy component of angular which is the JIT compiler.

So to avoid shipping the JIT compiler to production you need to use Ahead Of Time compilation. You'll find a cookbook here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

This way you will get a small and fast starting app - since the HTML template sources and angular compiler is not part of the bundle. Also there will be only one file.

I have a full example with an angular2 app with material design with compiled AOT-bundle in this repository:

https://github.com/fintechneo/angular2-templates

Also in the future the ng cli should be able to produce an AOT bundle for you, but right now the ng build --prod --aot feature is still experimental and it creates larger bundles than just following the AOT cookbook directly. Also it still seems like the bundle produced by ng cli has longer loading/starting time than the bundles produced using the AOT cookbook example.

Comment: So if I follow the cookbook for Ahead Of Time compilation, that will create a bundle that I can deploy to my dev and prod servers?

Comment: yes. and also a smaller bundle than angular cli is able to  produce as of today ( but I expect  that will be fixed very soon )